# MySQL - Selecting rows that do not have a match or that have with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I can't figure this out so far, I have these tables:

- **students** - Columns: id, name
- **stud_class** - Columns: students_id, class_id
- **class** - Columns: id, courses_id
- **courses** - Columns: id, name

I need to select the students that don't have a matching row in the **stud_class** table **OR** those who aren't in a class of a given course (the given course is a parameter).

For example: select the students that don't have any classes or those that are in a class, but not the class of the `course.id = 2`.

I did this so far, but it doesn't work, the query returns no rows. I know it's kind of confusing, but I don't know how to use the JOINS in this case.

```
SELECT  students.id, students.name 
FROM    students, stud_class, class
WHERE ( NOT (students.id = stud_class.students_id) )
  OR  ( (students.id=stud_class.students.id) AND 
        (stud_class.class_id=class.id) AND 
        ( NOT (class.course_id=2) )
      );
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but your query uses the older ANSI-89 style joins. Might want to look into switching to [ANSI-92 style JOINs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you're looking for all students that aren't in in the class of a certain course - regardless of whether they have other classes or not. In that case, does this work?

```
SELECT id, name FROM students
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT stud_class.students_id FROM stud_class, class
    WHERE stud_class.class_id = class.id
    AND class.courses_id = 2
)
```

The subquery gets the ids of all students who are in the class of course 2 (as per your example), and the main query gets the ids of all students who are not in that list.